# Binding the Json result to the Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to populate the drop down list using ajax but I'm getting an error. How to bind the Json result to the drop down list using ajax/jquery. So any help will be appreciated.
This is my Controller.

```
     public  JsonResult GetMonths(int YearId)
    {
        CCIRepository _repository = CCIRepository.CreateRepository();
        List<MonthListClass> list = new List<MonthListClass>();
        list =  _repository.GetMonthFromImportDate(YearId);
        return Json(new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text"));
    }
```

This is My Ajax code.

```
      <p>
    <h3>Year:</h3>@Html.DropDownList("Yearitems",       (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList, "Select Year")
    <h3>Month:</h3>@Html.DropDownList("MonthItems",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectMonthList,"Select Month")
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Search" /></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Yearitems").change(function () {
            debugger;
            alert($("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetMonths","AirtelManagement")',
                data: { YearId: $("#Yearitems>option:selected").attr("Value") },
                datatype: "Json",
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#MonthItems").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        debugger;
                        $("#MonthItems").append('<option>', {
                            value: item.value,
                            text: item.text
                        }, '</option>')
                    });
                    //$("#MonthItems").html(items);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An Error Occured");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What error is it that you are you getting?

Comment: error: function () {
                    alert("An Error Occured");
                }

Comment: this alert box i'm getting.

Comment: It means you aren't having success retrieving the data. Have you tried debugging the Application and actually see what the line
`return Json(new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text"));` does?

Comment: I would like to know if

`new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text")`

actually works

Comment: so can u tell how to return the data???

Comment: Just return the List. Can you tell me what are the properties of MonthListClass contains? so I can prepare an answer for you?

Comment: public int MonthSelectedId { get; set; }
        public string MonthName { get; set; }

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided I would make it like this

```
[HttpPost]
public  JsonResult GetMonths(int YearId)
{
    CCIRepository _repository = CCIRepository.CreateRepository();
    List<MonthListClass> list = new List<MonthListClass>();
    list =  _repository.GetMonthFromImportDate(YearId);
    return Json(list);
}
```

and in the script

```
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("GetMonths","AirtelManagement")',
      data:  JSON.stringify({ YearId: $("#Yearitems").val() }),
      datatype: "Json",
      success: function (data) {

                $("#MonthItems").html("");
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#MonthItems").append(new Option(item.MonthName, item.MonthSelectedId));
                });
                //$("#MonthItems").html(items);
            },
```

Try it

Comment: Make sure you add the [HttpPost] on top of your JsonResult method

Comment: How about now? I changed it again

Comment: Glad to be of help :)